# Add different pin color with MapKit in swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, swift2

I'm new in Swift. I'm trying to have different color pin or custom pin on specific pin. My code works. I've a purple pin, but I want make a difference between them. How can I do it? I think there something to do in MapView delegate method but I didn't find it.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapsViewController: UIViewController , MKMapViewDelegate{
    var shops: NSArray? {
        didSet{
            self.loadMaps()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadMaps()
        self.title = "Carte"
        self.map!.delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        // simple and inefficient example

        let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView()

        annotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        return annotationView
    }

    func loadMaps(){
//        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Carte"
        let shopsArray = self.shops! as NSArray
        for shop in shopsArray  {

            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: shop["lat"] as! Double,
                longitude: shop["long"] as! Double
            )


            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate   = location
            annotation.title        = shop["name"] as? String
            annotation.subtitle     = shop["addresse"] as? String

            map?.addAnnotation(annotation)

        }





        // add point



    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach is to use a custom annotation class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol (an easy way to do that is to subclass `MKPointAnnotation`) and add whatever properties are needed to help implement the custom logic.

In the custom class, add a property, say `pinColor`, which you can use to customize the color of the annotation.

This example subclasses MKPointAnnotation:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ColorPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var pinColor: UIColor

    init(pinColor: UIColor) {
        self.pinColor = pinColor
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Create annotations of type `ColorPointAnnotation` and set their `pinColor`:

```
let annotation = ColorPointAnnotation(pinColor: UIColor.blueColor())
annotation.coordinate = coordinate
annotation.title = "title"
annotation.subtitle = "subtitle"
self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

In viewForAnnotation, use the `pinColor` property to set the view's `pinTintColor`:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)

        let colorPointAnnotation = annotation as! ColorPointAnnotation
        pinView?.pinTintColor = colorPointAnnotation.pinColor
    }
    else {
        pinView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks you very much ! i'll try this, but i'm not understand one thing, where can i define the ' resueID ' ? is the id of one point ?? Sorry for my bad english i'm french... Thanks for you help again :)

Comment: You can define `reuseId` in `viewForAnnotation ` :-) e.g. `let reuseId = "pin"`

Comment: This works only on iOS 9 and above, What about < iOS 9 ??

Comment: @Shameerjan You can change pin color to red/green/purple before iOS 9. `pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Purple`  You can NOT change other color.

Comment: I think `pinView!.canShowCallout = true` would be a great addition to the mapView delegate function in the if clause.