# How do I change the color of one pin in my mapView?

Tags: swift, colors, annotations

I have a simple program written in swift. It does an MKLocalSearch for specific types or restaurants (say, "Italian Restaurant") and plots the pins on a MKMapView with annotation pins at the coords of the restaurant. I load a table view with the names and addresses of the restaurants found. All the pins are red. How do I change the color of that one pin that corresponds to the selected restaurant in the Table View?? I have the MKMapItem objects for each restaurant in an array so I can get all the coords. I have identified which annotation pin I want to change by matching the coords of the annotation to that of the MKMapItem.

The 'row' is the index of the tableViewCell which corresponds to the MKMapItem in the itemArray. I've read a number of posts regarding this and everyone only speaks about changing ALL the Pins green (or whatever color you set) - I just want one changed so it stands out from the others.

func colorPin(row: Int) {

```
    for ann in mapView.annotations {

        //print("PinName: \(String(describing: ann.title))")
        let long = ann.coordinate.longitude
        let lati = ann.coordinate.latitude

        if itemArray[row].mapItem.placemark.location?.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: lati, longitude: long)) == 0 {

            print("PinName: \(String(describing: ann.title))") // confirms I have the right pin

            // CHANGE PIN GREEN HERE //

        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: have a look .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33535363/4003548

Comment: I read that post. I'll dabble with it tomorrow. However, that code seems to color the pin when it's dropped.... I want to change the color of a pin that already exists in the view. Would I have to remove the existing and and then drop the colored pin?

Comment: yes you need to replace the annotations if you need any change after.

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav - I suspected as much. I'll screw around with that tonight to see what I can do.